# Disponibilizar na view dados de relacionamento polimórfico Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tenho as models Trainer, Modality e Image usando Polymorphic Relations do Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Quero disponibilizar esses dados na view e para isso fiz:

AppServiceProvider.php:

```
namespace Powerzone\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Powerzone\Image;
use Powerzone\Modality;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $modalities = Modality::all();
    View::share('modalities', $modalities);
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

View:

```
@extends('site.index')

@section('content')
<section>
    @foreach($modalities as $value)
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('/storage/imagem.jpg') }}">
    <h1>{{$value->name}}</h1>
    <p>{{$value->description}}</p>
    @endforeach
</section>
@endsection
```

Modality.php

```
namespace Powerzone;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Modality extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description',
];

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Powerzone\Image', 'imageable');
}

}
```

Trainer.php

```
namespace Powerzone;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trainer extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description',
];

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Powerzone\Image', 'imageable');
}
}
```

Image.php

```
namespace Powerzone;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'imageable_id',
    'imageable_type',
];

public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
}
```

Gostaria de disponibilizar as respectivas imagens relacionadas a model Modality apenas.

Comment: Coloque os três `model` na pergunta? Completos!

Comment: Coloquei os models completos.

Comment: Acho que isso resolve: `$modalities = Modality::with('images')->get();` e na `View` acesse `$modalities->images`

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado